# Does the Samsung Galaxy S6 record video using H.265?

Tags: video-recording, samsung-galaxy-s-6

The AnandTech review mentions H.265 encode capability in the SoC but does not mention codecs in the video review.

Does video of any size (1080p, 4Kp30, 720p120, ...) get encoded using H.265 on Samsung Galaxy S6?

Edit: Quote from [the article](http://anandtech.com/show/9146/the-samsung-galaxy-s6-and-s6-edge-review/2):

> Beyond the swap from a LPDDR3 memory controller to a LPDDR4 capable one, the only other at first noticeable major functional overhaul on the SoC seems to be that the dedicated HEVC decoder block has been removed and HEVC encoding and decoding capability has been merged into Samsung's MFC (Multi-Function Codec) media hardware acceleration block.

Comment: Could you add the link to the review you mentioned on the question? I only found that S6 supports playing H.265 video, but couldn't find anything if it's using H.265 for encoding, though it can record on 1080p/60fps, 2160p/30fps, 720p/120fps.

Comment: @AndrewT.: added a link and a quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GSM Arena have posted a review](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s6-review-1227p9.php) of the Galaxy S6 which includes a downloadable 2160p video clip. Running it through `mplayer` reports the following:

```
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 54.35.0 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
```

I take this to mean the device records in h264 only.